# Is the language that consists of machine configurations whose language is a subset of even palindromes semi-decidable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Let $PAL = \{ww^R\ | w\in\{0,1\}^*\}$.

Then let $A = \{\langle M\rangle \ | \textit{M is a Turing Machine and } L(M)\subseteq PAL\}$

Is A semi-decidable (Turing recognizable or recursively enumerable)?

My try!

I said it is so here is my proof, tell me if I am way off base or tell me if A ought not to semi-decidable in the first place.

$\underline{Proof}$

A is semi-decidable by The Certificate Theorem, which states that:

If $A\subseteq\Sigma^*$ then $A\in SD$(semi-decidable) iff there is some decidable relation, $R\subseteq \Sigma^* \times \Sigma^*$, such that $\forall x\in\Sigma^*$, $x\in{A}$ iff $\exists y$ such that $R(x,y)$ holds.

We know that if $x\in{A}$ that means that $x=\langle M\rangle$, so we can choose $y = \langle M,w\rangle$ where $w\in{PAL}$. What we know is that when $M$ takes $w$ as an input it will accept (since we choose $w$ as an input), if that is the case then $w\in{L(M)}\subseteq{PAL}$. That means that $A\in{SD}$. QED

Any help would be greatly appreciated, have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown is that the language of Turing machines accepting *at least one* even palindrome is semi-decidable. However, your question is interested in the language of Turing machines accepting *only* even palindromes, which is rather different. The complement of this language is the language of Turing machines accepting *at least one* word which *isn't* an even palindrome, and so *the complement* is semi-decidable according to your argument. This still leaves open the question of whether the *original* language is semi-decidable (and so decidable).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you give a suggestion on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: @InsigMath Hint: Rice's theorem.

Comment: We have not learned Rice's Theorem so I don't think it would be appropriate (well okay we have been shown it passively but told not to ever rely on it).

Comment: @Yuval: I don't think that "the complement of this language is the language of Turing machines rejecting at least one even palindrome".

Comment: @InsigMath Go read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). Congratulations: you just learned Rice's theorem. OK, if a question specifically states you're supposed to do something from first principles, then you should do that; but there's no such thing as knowledge that it would be inappropriate to use.  (Except for insider-trading. ;-) )

Comment: Hehe thank you @David Richerby, I am always for learning more :P, I just meant that for this question we are not supposed to use it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Rice's theorem will help in knowing if $A$ is undecidable. How does it help in showing some language *is* semi-decidable?

Comment: @Dai It's been shown that $\bar{A}$ is semi-decidable; the question asks whether $A$ is also semi-decidable. If $A$ and $\bar{A}$ are *both* semi-decidable, that would imply something about the decidability of $A$ and Rice's theorem tells us whether that implication is reasonable, or a contradiction.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I wrote my answer below along that line. Simply saying "Rice's theorem" is in my opinion unnecessary and misleading.

Answer (score 1):

My first hint is that your proof of $A \in SD$ is wrong. Assume that $M$ accepts only even palindromes, how are we supposed to certify that?

However, if you look at $\bar{A}$, which consists of $\langle M  \rangle$ such that $L(M) \not \subseteq PAL$, so $M$ must accept some string which not even palindrome. Hint: Can we apply the Certificate Theorem for this case? If so then $\bar{A} \in SD$.

It remains to show if $\bar{A}$ is decidable. If you can show that $\bar{A}$ is undecidable, then we can easily conclude $A\not \in SD$. (How?)

Comment: Thank you, I guess I got this backwards since I wanted to show that $\overline{A}$ was not semi-decidable by means of reduction. I will think of showing that $\overline{A}$ is semi-decidable then.

Comment: I'm still getting used to how to approach these problems ... thank you for the help though!

Comment: Yeah now that I think about it, showing that $\overline{A}$ is semi-decidable by means of the Certificate Theorem would not be too difficult. Then showing it is not decidable by a reduction with maybe the universal Turing machine would not be too hard either... cause I know that  if $\overline{A}$ is not decidable, that means that $A$ must also not be semi-decidable!

Comment: Why universal TM? We just need to reduce some undecidable problem to it!

Comment: By universal TM I mean $A_{TM} = \{\langle M,w\rangle\ \ |M \textit{ is a Turing Machine and M accepts w} \}$, I could also do it with $HB = \{\langle M\rangle \ | \textit{M is a TM and M halts on a blank tape}\}$